# Incrimenting value DOWN wont print out

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, for-loop, increment

Having an issue printing the results of `i` when I'm incrementing DOWN starting from `startVal` and ending at `endVal` with an increment of `incVal`.

the first if statement is printing correctly and I had THOUGHT that the second else if statement should be fairly similar however even though my original values; for EX: if `startVal = 100`, `endVal = 10`, and `incVal = -1`, it jumps to the else if statement correctly (tested with a basic print statement) but the `for loop` doesn't seem to work and not print out the results of `i` like it should.

```
                if ((startVal < endVal)  &&  (incVal >= 1))
                {  
                     for (int i = startVal; i <= endVal; i += incVal)
                     {
                          System.out.println(i);
                     }

                }
                //  else if incrimenting down
                else if((startVal > endVal)  &&  (incVal <= -1))
                {
                     for (int i = startVal; i <= endVal; i -= incVal)
                     {
                          System.out.println(i);
                     }

                }
```

Is there something stupid I'm messing up here? I've tried different things inside the for loops to get i to print but it doesn't work the correct way..

Comment: Not sure I understand the logic of the else/if and loop: if `startVal > endVal` evaluates to true, then i is initialized to startVal, which is greater than endVal, hence i <= endVal evalutes to false and loop terminates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you didn't change the for loop in the else clause

```
for (int i = startVal; i >= endVal; i += incVal)
{
     System.out.println(i);
}
```

edit: incValue should also be increasing since you have i=-1, thanks mstbaum

Comment: It should also be `i += incVal` because `incVal` will be negative.

Comment: Thanks guys! @Ryan just as I thought i was being stupid, I realized the main problem i had a negative number in incVal and I was trying to do `-=`... thanks for showing me hah

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that if `(startVal > endVal)` is `true`, your first iteration of your for loop will be be `false` because `int i = startVal; i <= endVal`, which evaluates in the first iteration as `startVal <= endval`.

You are also decrementing by a negative number (guaranteed by your `incVal <= -1` condition), which will result in `i` actually because of `i -= incVal`.